# Are irreducible polynomials and irreducibles (in an integral domain) different?

Tags: abstract-algebra

There's this theorem that you can factor polynomials (in $\mathbb{Z}$[x]) into polynomials of lower degrees r and s in $\mathbb{Q}$[x] iff you can factor that polynomial into polynomials of the same degrees r and s in $\mathbb{Z}$[x]. But when we reached the topic of irreducibles, $2x^2 + 2$ is an irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$[x] but not an irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$[x] because 2 is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$. Am I missing something or are those two 'irreducibles' different?

Answer (score 5):

What you're missing is that the theorem you mention, Gauss's Lemma, only tells you when polynomials factor into two polynomials of lower degree.  $2X^2+2 = 2(X^2+1)$ is not such a factorization, so even though $2X^2+2$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, Gauss's Lemma still applies—if you apply it properly.

The way I would state it is this: A polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ which is *primitive* (the GCD of its coefficients is $1$) is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: Note a polynomial which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is automatically primitive.